# Finsler or Lagrange geometry package?

Tags: symbolic, geometry

I was wondering if there exist any packages or examples of work on Finsler-Lagrange geometry. I need it to do symbolic calculations, as for example calculations of non-linear connection coefficients, or simplification of complicated tensorial expressions using identities. I haven't been able to find anything so far, the most promising was the "Ricci" package but I'm not sure it's the right choice for tasks like mine.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!